# Trying to create a very basic game, but experiencing some bottlenecking issues (I think)!

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash

I'm using Adobe Flash Professional CS6 to create the game. I'll post the code under. Be noticed that there are two symbol I've created using Flash that are not made by code. These symbols are the Crosshair symbol, and the Hitbox symbol. Basically, the objective of the game is to click the Hitbox symbol. My issue is that I am experiencing what seems to be bottlenecking issues. When I click the Hitbox symbol a lot of times with a fast timer the score doesn't register. I am pressuming that this comes from the (maybe) ineffective movement algorithm. But I can't really seem to find room for improvement. Some help would be appreciated.

Be noticed, I had to change the timer from `Timer(1)` to `Timer(30)`. This made the bottlenecking issue a little bit better, but made the game less fluent.

Aah, and the reason as to why I am using the `directionCheckerY` and `directionCheckerX` variables is that I will later in the development add random movement. A random timer will change these to either 0 and 1, creating random movement.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

// Variables

var directionCheckerX:int=0;
var directionCheckerY:int=0;
var pointChecker:int=0;

// Croshair

var crosshair:Crosshair = new Crosshair();
addChild(crosshair);
Mouse.hide();

function moveCrossEvent (evt: MouseEvent) {
    crosshair.x = mouseX;
    crosshair.y = mouseY;
    evt.updateAfterEvent();
}

// Hitbox

var hitbox:Hitbox = new Hitbox();
addChild(hitbox);
hitbox.x=50;
hitbox.y=50;

// Timer

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(30);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerEvent);
myTimer.start();
function timerEvent(evt:TimerEvent) {
    // Border code (Keeps the Hitbox away from out of bounds)
    if (hitbox.x <= 0) {
        directionCheckerX = 1;
    } else if (hitbox.x >= 550) {
        directionCheckerX = 0;
    }
    if (directionCheckerX == 0) {
        hitbox.x-=2;
    } else {
        hitbox.x+=2;
    }
    if (hitbox.y <= 0) {
        directionCheckerY = 1;
    } else if (hitbox.y >= 400) {
        directionCheckerY = 0;
    }
    if (directionCheckerY == 0) {
        hitbox.y-=2;
    } else {
        hitbox.y+=2;
    }
}

// EventListeners

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moveCrossEvent); 
hitbox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hitboxEvent);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stageEvent);

function hitboxEvent (evt:MouseEvent) {
    pointChecker+=1;
    outputTxt.text = String(pointChecker);
    evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
    //evt.updateAfterEvent();
}
function stageEvent(evt:MouseEvent) {
    pointChecker-=1;
    outputTxt.text = String(pointChecker);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, I'm not a game developer.

Actually, sometimes there is no big difference between a `Timer` with 1 millisecond interval and another one with 30 milliseconds interval because it's [depending on the SWF file's framerate or the runtime environment ...](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html) but here, what about using an `Event.ENTER_FRAME` event instead of a `Timer` ? because as Adobe said [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c36cfb8137124318eebc6-8000.html#WS4bebcd66a74275c36cfb8137124318eebc6-7ffb) about Timers versus ENTER_FRAME events :

> Choose either timers or ENTER_FRAME events, depending on whether content is animated.
>
> Timers are preferred over Event.ENTER_FRAME events for non-animated content that executes for a long time.

and in your case the content is animated (even if your game is still basic).

Then you can use a var to set the speed of your `hitbox` which you can update at any time :

```
var speed:int = 2;

function timerEvent(evt:TimerEvent): void 
{    
    // ...

    if (directionCheckerX == 0) {
        hitbox.x -= speed;
    } else {
        hitbox.x += speed;
    }

    // ...

}
```

Hope that can help.